# CSS Image Sprites not working in IE 11 but working fine in chrome

Tags: html, css, jsp, sprite, css-sprites

MY CSS is this

```
.ui-icon { width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(images/ui-icons_256x240.png); }
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon {width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(images/ui-icons_256x240.png); }
.ui-widget-header .ui-icon {width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(images/ui-icons2_256x240.png); }
```

and for positioning I am using this

```
.ui-icon-closethick { background-position: -96px -128px; }
```

My jsp is

```
<a href="#" class="..."><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" unselectable="on"></span></a>
```

This is working perfectly fine in chrome but I cant see image in IE. Please guide me.
thanks :)

Comment: Can you post a fiddle to show your issue. you can refer https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sprites_img for details too.

Comment: the code I shared is working with Chrome but isnt working with IE. That is my issue. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add `display: inline-block` to the span (or the class).

**EDIT:**
Works here -- sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="de"><head>
<style>
.ui-icon { width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(ui-icons_256x240.png); display: inline-block; }
.ui-icon-closethick { background-position: -96px -128px; }
</style></head>
<body>
    <a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" unselectable="on"></span></a>
</body></html>
```

with this PNG used: [Sample Sprite](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/dev/images/a/aa/Ui-icons_222222_256x240.png/revision/latest?cb=20121101014331&format=original)

Works in Chrome, IE11, Edge.

EDIT2: Imgur Link with result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpSOC.jpg

Comment: I changed my css to .ui-icon { width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(images/ui-icons_469bdd_256x240.png);display: inline-block; }  still it is not displaying on IE

Comment: did same for other two class as well

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added inline-block, apart from this I dont see any dissimilarities between the code. My IE 11 by default opens in Document mode 8 (found in developer tool). changed the document mode to 8/9/10/edge. still facing the same issue.

Comment: the !DCOTYPE directive should force ie11 to open in edge mode. once you changed the mode in the dev tools in a tab, this setting becomes manual

Comment: one more PS: the thing is that a SPAN is by default display:inline and without content has zero width (even if you add a css width attribute). Setting display to inline-block, the span becomes an actual width => for debugging purposes you could add `background-color: red` or something like that to check the SPAN is actually visible and has size 16x16

Comment: Can we [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177647/discussion-between-ayush-and-ipirat).

Comment: I removed the background image and added background-color:black in the css, I can see the black block, but I cant find why the image isn't getting loaded